# Spring Boot Integration Testing with Plugins

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that supports plugins. Plugins are jar files added to the core application docker container when deployed. The core application scans the plugin jars and adds components to the context.

I am looking for the best way to integration test the plugins with the core application. To that end, I added the core application jar as a test-scoped dependency for the plugins, but I'm not sure how run the tests with the full application context. I tried adding the primary configuration class from the core application to the @SpringBootTest annotation on the plugin tests, but I'm getting a cannot find symbol compilation error, so apparently that will not work with classes inside dependency jars.

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = { CoreApplication.class },
    properties = { 
"spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false","spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=false"} // disable 
consul to avoid errors
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class APluginTest {
```

Any suggestions on how I should wire these integration tests for plugins?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe better way to test somewhere in separate env, deploy your service with plugins into some env let's call it 'mock', and create let's call acceptance tests that will run in this environment calling actual service that's already up

Comment: Thanks Anton. That's my fallback, but I was hoping I could establish a pattern to allow plugin developers to easily test their plugins during the development process. If possible, I do not want them to have to wait for CICD testing to validate a change.

Comment: Maybe you can look how testcontainers team implement their solutions or you can look on way to test spring-cloud-stream applications. For example, when you're testing it you need to add such dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
        </dependency>